# Xamarin.Android binding Call java Object method

Tags: java, xamarin, xamarin.android, jnienv, java-binding

I created java binding library via visual studio extension called Xamarin.GradleBinding. I added `ru.rambler.android:swipe-layout:1.0.14` package and while using its `SwipeLayout`, it all works well. But unfortunately it did not created corresponding C# classes or anything like that. I tried adding package manually but still nothing.

I checked the [source on GitHub](https://github.com/rambler-digital-solutions/swipe-layout-android). `SwipeLayout` has a `public void` method `reset()` without parameters:

```
public void reset()
```

I try to call this method from c# with `JNIEnv`.

```
IntPtr type = JNIEnv.FindClass("ru/rambler/libs/swipe_layout/SwipeLayout");
IntPtr method = JNIEnv.GetMethodID(type, "reset", "()V");
try
{
    JNIEnv.CallObjectMethod(_swiper.Handle, method);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    var s = ex.Message;
}
```

Type and method are successfully found but calling

```
JNIEnv.CallObjectMethod(_swiper.Handle, method);
```

This method crashes the app, it does not even goes into catch block.

Tt must be cause of  the `_swiper.Handle` first parameter. 
`_swiper` field is of type `ViewGroup` since `SwipeLayout` is derived from `ViewGroup`. 
I can't find how to get the pointer of the view to pass that method.

while debugging, when I investigate the `_swiper`, it seems to be the correct instance of `SwipeLayout`

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure build gradles don't exist in xamarin

Comment: it works, it displays the custom view when I add in AXML file, but there is no c# equivalent class

Comment: what class are you looking for

Comment: @G.hakim SwipeLayout

Comment: what does it do? there will probably be a xamarin android equivalent for it why not use that

Comment: @G.hakim i use it in collection where you swipe view and see some actions. This is simple to use and has a good experience, thats why i want to use it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163326/discussion-between-mister-giga-and-g-hakim).

Comment: I would say that you are going down the wrong path for this binding library. Rather than going directly to JNI, you should be trying to "help" the binding generator, so you get a more accurate and complete binding. For example a typical reason C# classes are not bound is that you are missing a reference jar dependency. In this library we see `com.android.support:support-core-ui:24.2.1` - https://github.com/rambler-digital-solutions/swipe-layout-android/blob/develop/swipe-layout/build.gradle#L28

Comment: Given how large this library is, it would actually probably be more beneficial to convert to C# instead of binding as it's only 1 class.

Comment: See my blog: https://www.jon-douglas.com/2016/10/28/porting-android-libraries-to-xamarin-android/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done a rewrite of the control to C# with `Xamarin.Android`. It is available [here on my GitHub](https://github.com/MartinZikmund/swipe-layout-xamarin-android/tree/develop/SwipeLayoutXamarin/SwipeLayoutXamarin), but I haven't had time to test it yet, so it might have bugs.

But you can try it and potentially fix the bugs I have missed during the rewrite using the original `.java` source code.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it and tell you results

Comment: sorry, it has bugs in really. it draws layout well, but calling Reset on it makes it dissapear while it shall reset state, also if i swipe fast the layout swipes too much. :( but thank you for your efforts

Comment: But feel free to fix the issues, it should be just oversights :-)

Comment: I need that library because I want it's functionality without looking inside the code. I will also need to reference other java packages and I can't sit and rewrite every library I may need

Comment: I understand. You will definitely need to look into the Xamarin Java library binding a bit more to learn about the ways to give the binder a hint of how to bind the classes. It should be possible with a bit of help to bind any native library.

Comment: Yearly unclosed answer review - @mister_giga, if this helped, please consider accepting the answer as solution so that the question is closed.